# How to directly access translated variables by language

Tags: localization, variable, globals

I have a localized, two language site (en and fr) that I have a translated global variable set for. My question is: is there a way on a Craft 3 template to directly access a translation of a variable that isn't the same as the currentSite language. Specifically, I'd like to show both translations of the same variable on one page.

I am getting the variable with this currently: `siteOwnerInfo.siteOwner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Craft docs page for "Globals" under [Querying Globals](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/globals.html#querying-globals).

You can pass a site ID number to an element query to get globals from another site/language. For example, if your French site id number is 2, you could do this:

```
{% set siteOwnerInfoFrench = craft.globalSets()
  .handle('siteOwnerInfo')
  .siteId(2).one() %}

{{ siteOwnerInfoFrench.siteOwner }}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for the assist!